# Wcf suddenly hangs (web get operation)

Tags: c#, wcf

I read lot of articles about fact that client should close connection with `client.Close()` so WCF default limit does not get exceeded  Thing is, I have WCF WebGet operation which basicly just returns an image.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
[ValidationBehavior]
public interface IImagesService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "ImagesGet4")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Image/{partner}/{id}/{image}_{width}_{height}.jpg")]
    Stream ImagesGet2(string partner, string id, string image, string width, string height);
  }
```

In this situation client is browser and whatever I do with wcf configuration does not help. `maxConnections,maxReceivedMessageSize,maxBytesPerRead`  and lot of other parameters are maxed out and still no luck.

**EDIT :**
This is additional code:
`ImageGet` method which is called by service:

```
       public Stream ImagesGet(string partner, string id, string image, string      width = null, string height = null)
        {
           WSData.EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.ClientIp("");
           WSData.EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.ServicePath("");
           WSData.EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Message( DateTime.Now + " | " + partner );


        bool cache;
        var images = new Images();
        var stream = images.ImagesGetStream(out cache, partner, id, image, width, height);

        if (cache)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=604800");
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.LastModified = DateTime.Today;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(id);
        }

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        OperationContext clientContext = OperationContext.Current;
        clientContext.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Dispose();
        });


        return stream;
    }
```

The `ImagesGetStream` method which is called by the above method is :

```
 public Stream ImagesGetStream( out bool cache, string partner, string id, string image, string width = null, string height = null, string background = null )
    {

        string PARTNER = partner;
        cache = true;

        try
        {
            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Load( 10, "DatabaseCall" );
            var img = ImagesDL.GetImage( PARTNER, new PrimaryKey( id ) );
            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Unload( 13 );

            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Load( 14, "GettingImageDir" );
            var imagesRoot = Path.Combine( BaseConfiguration.GetDocumentsSharedDirectory( PARTNER ), img.Url );


            var isWatermarked = img.Group.Contains( "WEBES" ) == false && ( partner.ToUpper() == "ZG-ADRIAGATE1" || partner.ToUpper() == "LENIO-ADRIAGATE2" || partner.ToUpper() == "LENIO" );

            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Unload( 15 );

            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Load( 16, "ImageToStream" );
            var stream = new FileStream( imagesRoot, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read );
            EventLogs.MinimalEventSource.Log.Unload( 17 );


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
            {
                var isBackground = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(background);

                int widthp = 0;
                int heightp = 0;

                int.TryParse(width, out widthp);
                int.TryParse(height, out heightp);

                return ResizeImage(partner, stream, new Size(widthp, heightp), isBackground, img.Guest, isWatermarked, background);
            }
            else if(img.Group.Contains("WEBES") == false) {

                Image imgToResize = Image.FromStream(stream);

                if(imgToResize.Width > imgToResize.Height && imgToResize.Width > 2048 )
                    return ResizeImage(partner, stream, new Size(2048, 1536), false, img.Guest, isWatermarked, background);

                else if (imgToResize.Width < imgToResize.Height && imgToResize.Height > 2048)
                    return ResizeImage(partner, stream, new Size(1536, 2048), false, img.Guest, isWatermarked, background);

                else if (imgToResize.Width == imgToResize.Height && imgToResize.Height > 2048)
                    return ResizeImage(partner, stream, new Size(2048, 2048), false, img.Guest, isWatermarked, background);
            }

            return isWatermarked ? WatermarkingImage( partner, stream, img.Guest, isWatermarked ) : stream;



        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            cache = false;
            return new FileStream( AppPath + @"\App_Resorces\NoImage.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read );
        }
    }
```

This is relevant part of config:

```
<service name="WSTraveller.ImagesService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="soapBehavior" contract="WSTraveller.IImagesService" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding" bindingName="soapBinding" bindingNamespace="http://ws.adriagate.com/TRWS/ImagesService.svc/soap"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" contract="WSTraveller.IImagesService" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" bindingName="webBinding" bindingNamespace="http://ws.adriagate.com/TRWS/ImagesService.svc/pox"/>
  </service>
```

...

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="soapBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Have you ever traced through the server code and tried to replicate your issue while debugging?

Comment: Yes, once stopped working after database call, but it seems unlikely for me that database is the issue because it is very simple query. Select one element from table Images. I don't have more details now before monday because my collegue works to solve this problem.

Comment: This question cannot be answered even with infinite bounty without code. It seems like you were able to repro the problem(?). Post the call stack of the hanging thread including external code.

Comment: It is not possible to manually reproduce problem or to make it hangs. It happens in production enviroment few times a day. We though problem was because some images are really really big so we make resizing to maximum 2400×1800, but this thing also didn't help.

Comment: At least post full code of that ImageGet

Comment: I will post tomorrow.

Comment: You can also check the http log under the [ErrorLoggingDir](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364457.aspx) (default is `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles`)

Comment: To be honest my collegaue works to solve this problem in company but as far as I know there is no error in log files. It simply works ok, and hangs few times a day meaning all other request will not be served until application pool is restarted.

Comment: @Vlado just double check that there is no error also in that *specific log* file, if you have a chance to do that... Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: I will double check to be sure, but collegaue told be that there is no error, just few times a day wcf service hangs (things that are tried so far are: setting different wcf options, reducing maximum image size to 2400×1800. Next, we will cache image table to be sure there is no database issues which will help performance anyway)

Comment: Had the same issue myself, turns out it was actually the size of the image. It did not exceed the defined "maxReceivedMessageSize" etc. variables but still caused the program to hang. 

For me the solution was the break the image up into chunks of 4096 and then do the receiving part the same way putting all those chunks together. I thought it could not have been that but after that change, we have never had an issue since. 

Good luck and if you need help with the implementation I'd be glad to help.

Also it might be worth noting that our images are converted to Base64String.

Comment: There are also a _lot_ of IDisposable things in that code that are not being disposed, which can sometimes lead to bad behavior (file handles dangling, causing other readers to block, stray network connections not getting closed, that sort of thing).

In particular, all FileStreams (actually, all Streams) and all Images are disposable, and you are creating quite a few intermediate versions of those that aren't getting Disposed)

Comment: @ChadNedzlek where specifically? I see they are disposing them.

Comment: In the ImagesGetStream method, "imgToResize" isn't diposed, nor is "stream" in the exception path, and I assume "var img" is also an image, and also not diposed. Nor are they returned from that method, so they can't be getting disposed by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents..check if this helps you:

1) try compressing the image using gzip stream or so, in our project we had to send huge datasets across wire using wcf so we used to compress and then send it across.

2) if the database is the bottleneck then you can make the db call asynchronous and use a queue mechanism to store the results and wcf client request would try and dequeue result at a regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

Before recycling the app pool, take a memory dump. If you have Visual Studio Enterprise, you can open the dump in a nice gui and see the stack trace of all .NET threads in the process. Since the app is no longer responding to requests, there's a very good chance most of the stack traces will be at the same location, which will tell you where in the code the problem is. Then you know where to focus your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the HTTP, TCP/IP and named pipe transports use buffered message transfers.
>
> Buffered transfers hold the entire message in a memory buffer until the transfer is complete.

Since you have not specified, in config, to use *Streamed*, it is using *Buffered* as transfer mode. Therefore, it is possible your process is running low on memory due to multiple (depending on number or requests) huge files being kept in memory.

Please make the changes and try again. I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, my colleague works on this problem, and I already suggested him this solution.